# Not able to concatenate variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert variable in string, but I am not able to properly escape special characters.
Below is my code:

```
  $('#myTab a[href="#Ledgers"]').tab('show')
```

I have variable like `TabContainerID`, `SecondTabID`

I need to replace `myTab` with `TabContainerID` and `Ledgers` with `SecondTabID`

Comment: `$('#' + TabContainerID + ' a[href="#' + SecondTabID + '"]').tab('show')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation can be done by using `+` in JavaScript

```
$('#' + TabContainerID + ' a[href="#' + SecondTabID + '"]').tab('show')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#' + TabContainerID + ' a[href="#' + SecondTabID + '"]').tab('show')`